# Slick result to json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

What I would like to do is inspired by this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonHttp

I would like to have `Person` that can have `Address` attached to them. It's many to many actually in my example, so a person can have multiple addresses and an address may be attached to multiple persons.

The query was not a problem. I get back: `Future[Seq[((Person, PersonAddress), Address)]]` from the DB layer.

My problem begins when I want to return the result as json. For a `Person` alone it would be simple, as the case class would already take care, but for such a Seq it's more complicated.

So I tried this:

1) DB just returns `Future[Seq[((Person, PersonAddress)]]` for now, to make things easier for me to understand

2) `case class PersonWithPersonAddress(person: Person, personAddress: PersonAddress)` was added to be a helper instead of using `Tuple2[Person, PersonAddress]`

3) I wrote the following writer:

```
 implicit val writes: Writes[PersonWithPersonAddress] = (
      (JsPath \ "person").write[Person],
      (JsPath \ "personAddress").write[PersonAddress]
    ) (unlift(PersonWithPersonAddress.unapply))
```

According to the compiler this is not enough.

> No Json serializer found for type PersonAddress. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Then I tried to add: 
`implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]`
`implicit val PersonAddressFormat = Json.format[PersonAddress]`

but I got

`(play.api.libs.json.OWrites[Person], play.api.libs.json.OWrites[PersonAddress]) does not take parameters`

I proceeded to manually write my `Writes[Person]` but this does not change a thing to `Json.format[Person]` of course.

Now I am out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough for you:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
implicit val personAddressFormat = Json.format[PersonAddress]
implicit val personWithPersonAddressFormat = Json.format[PersonWithPersonAddress]
```

If you'd still want to define `Writes` field-by-field, you should try this:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]
implicit val personAddressWrites = Json.writes[PersonAddress]
implicit val personWithAddressWrites: Writes[PersonWithPersonAddress] = (
  (__ \ "person").write[Person] and
  (__ \ "personAddress").write[PersonAddress]
)(unlift(PersonWithPersonAddress.unapply))
```